# Null check operator used on a null value- futter chat

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a  chat app with sending voice message. now I'm getting this error in my code. appreciate your help on this. I HAVE INSERTED FOLLOWING CODE ANS THEN ERROR APPEARS. Cant find a exact file error occurring.

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

[image: error image]

```
class SoundRecorder {

  FlutterSoundRecorder? _audioRecorder;
  bool _isRecorderInitialised = false;

  bool get isRecording => _audioRecorder!.isRecording;

  Future init() async {
    _audioRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
    await _audioRecorder?.openAudioSession(); //start recording


    //asking permisson
    final status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      throw RecordingPermissionException("Microphone permission");
    }
    await _audioRecorder!.openAudioSession();
    _isRecorderInitialised = true;
  }


  void dispose() {
    if (!_isRecorderInitialised) return;
    _audioRecorder!.closeAudioSession();
    _audioRecorder = null;
    _isRecorderInitialised = false;
  }

  Future _record() async {
    if (!_isRecorderInitialised) return;
    await _audioRecorder!.startRecorder(toFile: pathToSaveAudio);
  }

  Future _stop() async {
    if (!_isRecorderInitialised) return;
    await _audioRecorder!.stopRecorder();
  }

  Future toggleRecording() async {
    if (_audioRecorder!.isStopped) {
      await _record();
    } else {
      await _stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is in line number 186? it says that when you access isRecording, _audioRecorder is still null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like at some point you use the `!` operator to assert that `_audioRecorder` isn't null but it actually is. From the stack, I think this would be from the `isRecording` getter.

A simple fix to this would be to make the getter `bool get isRecording => _audioRecorder?.isRecording ?? false`, since if `_audioRecorder` is null, then you can't be recording, right?

Comment: can you tell me exactly where should I want to change in the code. didn't get the explanation sorry

Comment: You see where you have `bool get isRecording => _audioRecorder!.isRecording;` ? I am assuming, based on the error message, that at some point you are calling `isRecording` and it throws the error because `_audioRecorder` is null.

So, just add a `?` operator with `false` as fallback. `bool get isRecording => _audioRecorder?.isRecording ?? false;`